# mod-rewrite redirect but prevent direct access

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all content to:

```
www.example.com/public/...
```

but prevent direct access to

```
www.example.com/public/file1/
www.example.com/public/file2/
etc
```

The final URL should be:

```
www.example.com/file1/
```

I've tried this for redirecting and it works - but I dont know how to prevent direct access:

```
ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You probably got some downvotes before your edit because your initial question lacked any research effort. I'd suggest you to take the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 2):

After spending an inordinate amount of time trying to solve this problem, I found that the solution lies with the under-documented [`REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html#variables).

Add this to the beginning of your top-level `/.htaccess` code, and also to any `.htaccess` files you have under it (e.g. `/public/.htaccess`):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=200
RewriteRule ^ /public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

</IfModule>
```

Now, if the user requests `example.com/file1` then they are served the file at `/public/file1`. However, if they request `example.com/public/file1` directly then the server will attempt to serve the file at `/public/public/file1`, which will fail (unless you happen to have a file at that location).

**IMPORTANT:**

You need to add those lines to all `.htaccess` files, not just the top-level one in the web root, because if you have any `.htaccess` files below the web root (e.g. `/public/.htaccess`) then [these will override the top-level `.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#how) and users will again be able to access files in `/public` directly.

**Note about variables and redirects:**

Performing a redirect (or a rewrite) [causes the whole process to start again with the new URI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12333799/4421959), so any variables that you set before the redirect will no longer be set afterwards. This is done deliberately, because usually you do not want the final result to depend on how you got there (i.e. whether it was via a direct request or via a redirect).

However, for those special occasions where you **do** want to know how you got to a particular URI, you can use `REDIRECT_STATUS`. Also, any environment variables set before the redirect (e.g. with [`SetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif)) will still be available after the redirect, but [with `REDIRECT_` prefixed to the name of the variable](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html#variables) (so `MY_VAR` becomes `REDIRECT_MY_VAR`).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should clarify what's the expected behaviour when user tries to reach the real URL:

```
www.example.com/public/file1/
```

If by *prevent* you mean forbid, you could add a rule to respond with a [403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

**Update: The solution above doesn't work!**

I realized my previous solution always throws the 403 so it's worthless. Actually, this is kinda tricky because the redirection itself really contains `/public/` in the URL.

The solution that really worked for me is to append a *secret* query string to the redirection and check for this value on URL's containing `/public/`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1?token=SECRET_TOKEN [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /public/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !token=SECRET_TOKEN
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=403,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This way `www.example.com/file1/` will show `file1`, but `www.example.com/public/file1/` will throw a 403 Forbidden error response.

Concerns about *security* of this `SECRET_TOKEN` are discussed here: [How secure is to append a secret token as query string in a htaccess rewrite rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333170/how-secure-is-to-append-a-secret-token-as-query-string-in-a-htaccess-rewrite-rul/)

---

*If your URL's are expected to have it's own query string, like `www.example.com/file1/?param=value` be sure to add the flag [QSA](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).*

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1?token=SECRET_TOKEN [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I feel like this should be possible by setting and testing for a [variable](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html) instead of a query string, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Oh, that'd be really cool @HullCityFan852 Please, feel free to edit the answer or comment any success you got with this!

Comment: I got it working eventually. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553159/4421959), and the note about variables and redirects.

Comment: Good job @HullCityFan852!