# How secure is to append a secret token as query string in a htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite, token

I was doing some tests while trying to provide an answer to [mod-rewrite redirect but prevent direct access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326795/mod-rewrite-redirect-but-prevent-direct-access).

> *Original question goal is basically mask `example.com/public/foo` as `example.com/foo` while forbidding access to the real URL `example.com/public/foo`.*

Once I found a possible solution appending a *token* to the rewritten URL's Query String,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1?token=SECRET_TOKEN [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /public/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !token=SECRET_TOKEN
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=403,L]
```

I realized (with Chrome's DevTools) that I really can't see this token in the Request Headers.

[image: Headers Screenshot]

I understand that's because the first `RewriteRule` doesn't trigger a redirect on the client and all this rewrite process takes place in the server.

If I am right, this `SECRET_TOKEN` is secure, isn't it? *(By secure, I mean it can't be known by the client in any way)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily, the client should never see the `SECRET_TOKEN` - as you say, the rewrite is internal to the server.

However, it's possible the `SECRET_TOKEN` could get exposed under certain conditions, depending on the server config.

For example, using the code you posted, the `SECRET_TOKEN` could get exposed by requesting either `example.com/public` or `example.com/subdir` (where `subdir` is a subdirectory inside `/public`) - note the omission of the trailing slash.

1. **example.com/public** - If you were to request `/public` (no trailing slash) then mod_dir "corrects" this by appending a trailing slash, which is achieved with a 301 external redirect. However, the redirect does not occur immediately and your `RewriteRule` directive ends up rewriting this request (since the `REQUEST_URI` variable is still `/public` at this point - no trailing slash) to `/public/?token=SECRET_TOKEN` (note the trailing slash now on the directory). (The URL-path does not appear to be updated by the `RewriteRule` for some reason, as you might expect this to be `/public/public`, however, the query string is still appended. Maybe something to do with the subrequest that mod_dir issues? Not sure why?) Since a 301 has already been triggered by mod_dir, this response (containing the `SECRET_TOKEN`) is now sent back to the user as an *external redirect* and the `SECRET_TOKEN` is exposed.
2. **example.com/subdir** - A similar (but slightly different) thing would happen if there was a subdirectory `/public/subdir` and you requested `/subdir` (no trailing slash). Your `RewriteRule` directive kicks in first this time and internally rewrites the request to `/public/subdir?token=SECRET_TOKEN`. Ok so far. But then mod_dir kicks in and wants to append a trailing slash to `/public/subdir` - it does this with an external 301 redirect. So the request is now *redirected* to `/public/subdir/?token=SECRET_TOKEN` and the `SECRET_TOKEN` is exposed to the user (as well as the `/public` subdirectory, which was previously unknown).

However, using the query string in this way does have some other caveats:

1. As it stands, you are overwriting any other query string on the request.
2. To merge an existing query string on the request, you would need to specify the `QSA` flag on the `RewriteRule`. However, if a user then appended `?token=` on the request then they would override your `token` URL param if you wanted to read this using the `$_GET` superglobal in a PHP script. You could manually change the order of the query string parameters by explicitly including the `QUERY_STRING` server variable in the *substitution* instead of using the QSA flag - but this is a bit more messy (eg. what if there is no query string?).

Comment: Thank you so much for this complete answer! I've been doing `.htaccess` rewrites/redirects for years and still I've learnt a lot today!